# Using postMessage() on iframe by passing relative path

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I have a folder with the following files:

- index.html
- screens.html
- code.js
- screens-code.js
- style.css
- screens-style.css

**index.html** is my main page containing my layout and it includes an `iframe` with `src="screens.html"`. It works, however when I want to do `postMessage()` from **index.html** (which has added **code.js** file) to **screens.html** (it has added **screens-code.js**) I cannot do that with a relative path. I am doing like this (in main page's code.js file):

```
var frame = document.getElementById('innerScreen').contentWindow; // #innerScreen is iframe's ID
var hello = 'Message from screens.html file';
frame.postMessage(hello, frame.url); // or instead of <frame.url> i tried using just <screens.html> as relative path to HTML file
```

I get the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'.**

What's going on? I have all files in same folder, I don't run it by server (kind of XAMPP). Doesn't it work without server?

In **screens-code.js** I only have this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event)
{
   console.log('Success?');
}
```

But nothing happens except above errors.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**DEMO**
http://plnkr.co/edit/q9Whqt0RfA90UwxQkFDv?p=preview

So there, in console is an error 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null**

**[edit]**

This works, so adding `EventListener` which will wait for iframe to load:

```
frame.addEventListener('load', function() 
{
      iframe.postMessage('some testing message', '*');
});
```

Comment: Please post both **full** js files and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M). I suggest Plunker, you can actually recreate each file.

Comment: @zer00ne I added a demo.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris92 just need one more file that's pivotal `code.js`

Comment: @zer00ne It's there, but called `script.js` (Plunker named it like this by default).

Comment: Perfect, thank you, sir.

Comment: @zer00ne, so do you have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm testing on my own server since Plunker might have restrictions. At first I thought it may be that the origin might have to be an absolute URL, but that didn't work and neither did *. I gotta get back to work, but after work, I'll try different sub-domains.